# Stage scale mode error #1009

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, resize, window

I'm trying to create a simple Air/Flex app which loads in user selected image and then resizes the window so that the selected image fits into it. If I have understood correctly, I need to set stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE. However, when I call this I just get Error #1009 "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."
Below is my default application mxml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                       initialize="init();"
                       applicationComplete="complete();"
                       xmlns:local="*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->

    </fx:Declarations>


    <mx:MenuBar id="myMenubar" width="832" itemClick="menuHandler(event);" labelField="@label" depth="0">
        <fx:XMLList xmlns="">
            <item label="File">
                <item label="New" id="new"/>
                <item label="Open" id="open"/>
                <item label="Save" id="save"/>
                <item label="Save As" id="saveas"/>
                <item label="Quit" id="quit"/>
            </item>

            <item label="Edit">
                <item label="Undo" id="undo"/>
                <item label="Redo" id="redo"/>
                <item label="Preferences" id="preferences"/>
            </item>

            <item label="Level">
                <item label="New Room" id="newroom"/>
                <item label="Properties" id="properties"/>
            </item>

            <item label="Objects">
                <item label="Clickable" id="clickable"/>
                <item label="Character" id="character"/>
                <item label="Door" id="door"/>
                <item label="Treasure" id="treasure"/>
            </item>
        </fx:XMLList>


    </mx:MenuBar>

    <s:SpriteVisualElement id="flashpunk" depth="-2">
    </s:SpriteVisualElement>    

    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[

        import mx.collections.*;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.IUIComponent;
        import mx.events.MenuEvent;
        import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

        public var Maini:Main = new Main; 

            private function init():void
            {
                flashpunk.addChild(Maini);

            }

            private function complete():void
            {

                stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            }

            private function menuHandler(evt:MenuEvent):void  
            {
                // Don't open the Alert for a menu bar item that 
                // opens a popup submenu.

                    Alert.show("Label: " + evt.item.@label + "\n" + 
                        "Data: " + evt.item.@data, "Clicked menu item");
                    Maini.foo();

            }


        ]]>

    </fx:Script>



</s:WindowedApplication>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Also, after I have set scalemode, how exactly I can set the window size to a new size? My debug player doesn't seem to recognize even [SWF(width = "1200", height = "600")] or attempts to set stage width and height. I'm using Flash builder 4.6.

Comment: In a Flex component, you won't be able to access the stage unless the item is on the display list.  For a Flex Component, this won't happen until after the ApplicationComplete event fires from the apps main application.  Based on the code you've shared, I'm unsure if this is the issue.

Comment: I tried add ApplicationComplete event function, but with it I get same error. I updated my whole mxml code to the original post.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. Apparently I had some older build files around which messed the build.

Comment: As a followup to what @www.Flextras.com stated, ApplicationComplete will only be available on the TopLevelApplication. For all other components, you want to use the AddedToStage event instead before executing any code that requires the stage.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://killerspaz.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/access-to-the-stage-in-flex/ - During component initialization, you can access the stage through `this.systemManager` reference.

```
systemManager.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```